# Crossplatform product and information showing application

Tags: java, silverlight, flash, apache-flex, air

Want to create a simple app that runs locally whatever on PC or mobile devices, which shows various products information which would be loaded from local file system (documents, videos, htmls and so on). Furthermore it's able to configured later on.(change source directories, change button label.)

Please suggest what framework is well suited for developing this kind of application. Thanks.